# jQuery + One Page Scroll plugin: check if element hasClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [this plugin](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html) with jQuery and I have a div for a background image/color that fills the viewport. I'd like to change the background when a given section is active (the plugin is already configured to change the currently visible section's class to "active").

Here's the js I'm working with, but it's not changing anything. Markup seems fine—but it's just defaulting to the 'else' condition. Could there be a conflict with the plugin?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".main").onepage_scroll({
    sectionContainer: "section",
    loop: false
});


if ($('#test').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#project-image').css("background", "red");
} else {
    $('#project-image').css("background", "yellow");
}

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`afterMove`](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll#aftermovenext_page_index) event

```js
$(".main").onepage_scroll({
  sectionContainer: "section",
  loop: false,
  afterMove: function(index) {
    $('#project-image').css("background", $('#test').hasClass('active') ? "red" : "yellow");
  }
});
```